# react - react router - privateRoute - infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, infinite-loop

I'm trying to make a simple authentication system in my Single Page Application.
I want to disable all routes execpt `/login` for guest.
The way to know if the user is authenticated or a guest it's to know if there are an `access_token` in the `localStorage`.

When I'm starting the app the `Main` component is started. The component define the routes and know if the user is authenticated by check the `localStorage`.

The default route (`/`) is for render the `Home` component but, like this [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) of **react router** the `Home` component is protected by a `PrivateRoute` object.

The `PrivateRoute` object check if the user is authenticated. If yes, `Home` component is rendered, else the user is redirected to the `login`component at `/login`.

The `Login` component redirect the user to `/` in case of success and execute a callback to give the `access_token`.

The `Main` component define the callback, It's about to save the `access_token` in the `localStorage` and change the `state` for declare the user as authenticated. And now, the user can access the `Home` component.

My problem is, the `PrivateRoute` system always the check the user as a guest so it's always a redirection to `/login`. But when the are an `access_token` in `localStorage` the `Login` component redirect to the `Home` protected by the `PrivateRoute` and this is an infite loop despite the `handleLogin` callback.

Can you find a solution ?

---

**Main.jsx**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter, Link, Redirect, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import {Login} from "./Login"
import {Home} from "./Home";


class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this);
        this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
        this.state = {authed: localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== null};
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    }

    handleLogout(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
        this.setState({authed: false});
    }

    handleLogin(token) {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);
        this.setState({authed: token !== null});
    }

    render() {
        const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
            <Route {...rest} render={props =>
                this.state.authed()
                    ? (<Component {...props} />)
                    : (<Redirect to="/login"/>)
            }
            />
        );

        const LoginLogout = () => {
            return this.state.authed
                ? (<button onClick={this.handleLogout}>Logout</button>)
                : (<Link to="/login">Login</Link>);
        };

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <LoginLogout/>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <Route path="/login" component={() => <Login handleLogin={this.handleLogin}/>}/>
                    <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Home}/>

                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

if (document.getElementById('main')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('main'));
}
```

**Login.jsx**

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";

export class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            redirect: localStorage.getItem('access_token') !== null,
            token: null,
            loading: false,
            error: null
        };
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.props.handleLogin(this.state.token);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            error: null,
            loading: true
        });
        axios.post('/api/login', {
            'client_id': '3',
            'email': this.state.email,
            'password': this.state.password,
            'confirm_password': this.state.password
        }).then((response) => {
            let token = response.data.access_token;
            this.setState({
                redirect: true,
                token: token,
                loading: false
            });
        }, (error) => {
            console.error('error', error.response.data);
            this.setState({
                error: error.response.data,
                loading: false
            });
        });
    }

    render() {

        if (this.state.redirect)
            return (<Redirect to={"/"}/>);

        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="email">Email :</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                       disabled={this.state.loading}/>
                <label htmlFor="password">Password :</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value={this.state.password}
                       onChange={this.handleInputChange} disabled={this.state.loading}/>
                <button type="submit"
                        disabled={this.state.loading}>{this.state.loading ? "..." : "Se connecter"}</button>
                {this.state.error && (
                    <div>
                        <p>Erreur : {JSON.stringify(this.state.error)}</p>
                    </div>
                )}
            </form>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that in your login, in handleSubmit after getting the token, you're not calling your handleLogin from props so the token is set in the state of Main, which will be the one who manage the authentication.

Comment: When I do it, the handleLogin is not executed before the rendering. So the state is not update in time, and there are an infinite loop again.

Comment: My bad, you're right, I think I was doing it wrong. Thanks you !

Comment: I posted it as a response, since you said it answered your doubt :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `handleSubmit` function you need to call the `handleLogin` from props so the state is correctly updated in your container component.

```
 handleSubmit(event) {
...

.then((response) => {
            let token = response.data.access_token;
            this.setState({
                redirect: true,
                token: token,
                loading: false
            });
           // here, call the handle from props
           this.props.handleLogin(token);
        }

...
```

That way, your `this.state.authed` will have the proper value